# Python version and pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have just installed python 3.10 on my Ubuntu. I have installed two python versions - Python 3.8 and Python 3.10. This is what I see when I try:

```
python --version
Python 3.10.2

python3 --version
Python 3.8.10

pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

I would like to create venv in Python 3.10 but I cannot, because when I try `python -m venv venv/` I got `Error: Command '['/home/vojta/Desktop/INTERNET_HANDEL/HEUREKA/heureka-negativni-reviews/venv/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

How can I fix it, please?

Comment: did you try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy it returns error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'`. I can only uprgrade pip using `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @vojtam How did you install that 3.10 interpreter? With your system package manager? From source? Using a 3rd party tool?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the venv library for that version.  Try:

```
$apt-get install python3.10-dev python3.10-venv
```

Then:

```
$virtualenv --python=/your/path/python3.10 venv
```

Comment: `virtualenv` is not related to `python3.*-venv`. That package is for `venv` support.

Comment: Instead of installing piecemeal components, you can (and barring special cases, usually should) install a complete python installation with `apt install --install-suggests python3.X-full`